# Can Microsoft Excel work like an app ? Like submit a form and store values?

Tags: excel, store, form-submit

Is it possible to create a small app out of ms excel which will have a form in one sheet as a UI and it will have a seperate sheet as a backend for storing values submitted from that form?

Comment: yes it is although you didn't give enough information for anyone to actually help you do it.  You will need to use VBA to write code to actually perform the work.  Further you'd be better off using a database.  Access, more or less, does what you need without having to write much, if any, code.

Comment: Are you thinking of a single user desktop or a multi user network solution? For a network solution you can look at Google Docs, which allows to enter data via forms and email.

Answer (score 0):

Could also try using google forms and sheets - they work well together and removes the need to use so much code.